# Replace text in .bat file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have 2 folders in folder called C:\durvi\mmi_test\mmidurvi which are 
C:\durvi\mmi_test\mmidurvi\durvyauu
C:\durvi\mmi_test\mmidurvi\sgdf
Both these folders have Connections.xml file
I would like to replace any occurance of ql99015 with dd32261
A sample format of file is as below

```
<pre><anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">ql99015</anyType>  

<anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">ql99015_flowreeng_Anthony</anyType>  </pre>
```

I tried something like below but does not work:

```
for /D %%f in (c:\durvi\mmi_test\mmidurvi\*) do (  
cd %%f  
if not exist "Connections.xml" (echo this file does not exist)&goto :eof  
SETLOCAL=ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION  
ren "Connections.xml" "Connections1.xml"  
for /f %%a in (Connections1.xml) do (    
set write=%%a  
echo %%a   
if !write!=="ql99015" set write="dd32261"  
echo !write! >> Connections.xml  
)  
del "Connections1.xml"  
cd..  
)
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the script to:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /r %%a in (connections.xml) do (
  move "%%a" "%%a.temp"
  for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%b in ("%%a.temp") do (
    set write=%%b
    echo !write:ql99015=dd32261! >> "%%a"
  )
  del "%%a.temp"
)
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this and let you know

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked perfect :) , I just added the path where I was looking for the connections.xml 'FOR /R c:\durvi\mmi_test\mmidurvi\* %%a in (connections.xml) do ('